# for loop not executing on zero parameters

Tags: c++, for-loop, matrix, boost

I am a self-taught python & C programmer and Iam now trying to learn C++

As a small exercise, I tried to port a function I had created in a Python minigame of mine, that generates a random matrix, then averages it, to create a map with terrain elevation.

I tried implementing it in C++ using a trick with size_t and the maximum size of an array, which I have already used successfully in C before.

However, the for-loop in my AverageSurroundings seems not to run when it is ran on row or column 0. This is confirmed by the output on stderr (I don't know how to put it in the question, sorry) and causes a division by zero error, which should not happen. I have done a small fix, but I can't find the origin of the problem

Here is a minimal snippet showing the problem.

```cpp
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/assignment.hpp> //for <<= 
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

static const std::size_t n_rows = 3;

static unsigned int
AverageSurroundings(const boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<unsigned int> mat,
                 const std::size_t row, const std::size_t col) {
  std::uint_fast16_t sum = 0; // <= 9*255= 2295 => 12 bits
  std::uint_fast8_t count = 0;
  std::cerr << "AverageSurroundings(" << row << ',' << col << ") called." << '\n';
  for ( std::size_t r = row - 1; r <= row + 1; r++) {
    for (std::size_t c = col - 1; c <= col + 1; c++) { // these values should remain positive, so we just 
                                                       // need to check if we are smaller than n_rows, 
                                                       //thanks to the wraparound of size_t.
      std::cerr<<"r:"<<r<<" c:"<<c<<'\n'; // FIXME : loop not executing on first row/column
      if (r < n_rows && c < n_rows) {
        sum += mat(r, c);
        count++;
        std::cerr << "AverageSurroundings(" << row << ',' << col << "): Neighbour found at (" << r<< ',' << c << ")." <<'\n';
      }
    }
  }
  std::cerr << std::endl; // flushing and adding a blank line.
  return count ? static_cast<unsigned int>(sum / count):0; //  count is 8bits long so no overflow is possible, casting to silence warning.
  //added ? to avoid floating point error for debug. FIXME : This should NOT BE 0   
}

static const boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<unsigned int>
Average(const boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<unsigned int> mat,
        const std::size_t rows) {
  using boost::numeric::ublas::matrix;
  matrix<unsigned int> m(n_rows, n_rows);
  for (std::size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (std::size_t col = 0; col < rows; col++) {
      m(row, col) = AverageSurroundings(mat, row, col);
      std::cout << m(row, col) << '\t';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return m;
}
int main() {
  using boost::numeric::ublas::matrix;
  matrix<unsigned int> m(n_rows,n_rows); m <<=  0, 1, 2,
                                                 3, 4, 5,
                                                 6, 7, 8;
  std::cout<< "---- RESULT ----" << '\n'; 
  const matrix<unsigned int> m2 = Average(m, n_rows);
}
```

and the corresponding output.

```
---- RESULT ----
0   0   0   
0   4   4   
0   5   6
```

Any help on the issue and remarks or code formatting are welcome.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it should be SIZE_MAX (or whatever the C++ name) which is bigger than the size of the array. I thought this would allow to get the neighbours of m[0][0] without going negative. 

I have also tried with int, just now and the problem remains.

Comment: sorry, misread the code. Comment removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a call to `AverageSurroundings` with `row==0` and/or `col==0` (see your loop variables in `Average`).

But `std::size_t` is an **UNSIGNED** type... So when it's zero, minus 1, it underflows in `AverageSurroundings`'s loops and returns `0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF`... Which is obviously greater than `row+1` (or `col+1`). So the loop isn't executed not a single time.

Even without the underflow, you would still be outside your matrix, even with a proper "-1" as index...

Comment: Is there an easy way to make sure it's executed at least once (when l=row and c=column) ? Maybe using a do while ?

Comment: With such a `for`, no, at least not without some ugly tricks. End condition is tested before any body execution. You must use a `do { ... } while (cond) ;` to guarantee at least one execution. It would be better, when you're on edges/corner, to reduce your average to a 2x2, 2x3 or 3x2 set of values instead of being outside the initial matrix. Alternatively, you can also make a workaround to say that when it's "-1" for an index, use "0" instead - consider it as copying first/last rows and columns just outside the matrix just to make computation easier.

Comment: There are quite a few ways to handle edges for neighborhood operations. For averaging, " ignore" is indeed a reasonable choice. But other options such as "assume 0" are also valid. This is not a C++ issue; it's a math choice.

Comment: @MSalters For the sake of discussion, I always found that "extending" the matrix by repeating the edge rows/columns always produced better results (at least for blurring images...) than using 0 or reducing the number of cells used for the average. For texturing/paving, it's better to consider the matrix as a torus. But it's really a matter of maths, speed, precision, etc. and in no way a C++ problem.